Power Automate - When email arrives changes body of email when passed to action
I am trying to extract a link from an email. When I open the source code of the email in an editor I can see the link that I am looking for. However, after the email is received and I try to use the "body" of the email in an compose action, the link cannot be found.
Can somebody explain how this can happen?
I have tried all of the dynamic content related to outlook, but couldn't find a solution.

The when a new email arrives (v3) action (assuming you are not using a shared mailbox) will return three body properties.
Make sure you use the Body (The body of the message). That should contain the HTML tags and attributes as well.
With the below expression you should be able to retrieve the first link found in that body
first(split(last(split(triggerOutputs()?['body/body'], '<a href="')), '" '))


